# How to make Javascript execute when you scroll?

Tags: javascript, scroll, infinite-scroll

I'm creating a Tampermonkey script that allows you hide subreddits from the front page of Reddit. It works all good, but only on the first page. The problem is, when you start scrolling, Reddit loads in new items (infinite scrolling) and the code doesn't work for those new items that get added.

I tried to add an event listener, but this doesn't work. The items still appear when you are scrolling.

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){

document.querySelector('a[href*="politics"]').parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.style.display='none';

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code will select *one* element which matches that selector, navigate to an ancestor element, and set its display to `none`. The element remains in the document, and no other elements are affected; when future `scroll` events occur, the same element will be selected, and the same ancestor will be hidden (but its `display` is already `none`, so it doesn't do anything).

Iterate over *all* matching elements with `querySelectorAll`, and remove them from the DOM with `.remove()`:

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
  for (const a of document.querySelectorAll('a[href*="politics"]')) {
    a.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
  }
});
```